# Iterate over children of element selected through XPath

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, foreach, puppeteer

I'm trying to iterate over children of the first div element and get the textContent property. I can do with just a regular querySelectorAll ($$) and then loop over that array. However I need it to loop over an array that is created for children selected with XPath. Right now I have this code:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>This is the first div</div>
            <div>This is the second div</div>
            <div>This is the third div</div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

This is the JavaScript

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html');

await page.waitForXPath(('/html/body/div/div[2]'))
const [liveDiv] = await page.$x('/html/body/div/div[2]');
const [liveDivParent] = await liveDiv.$x('..');
const childArr = await liveDivParent.$x('/*')

childArr.forEach(async (el) => {

    const textC =  await el.getProperty('textContent');
    const textJ =  await textC.jsonValue();
    console.log(textJ)
})


await browser.close();
})();
```

Right now the issue is that when it puts everything into a single object so forEach only console logs this all at once

```
            hello
            Wasasp
            LOL
```

Instead of listing them with each loop, it's 5 in the morning here and I'm exhausted but very frustated that I couldn't figure it out. If you have any tips or suggestions, I appreciate it very much! Thanks :D

Comment: _" forEach only console logs this all at once"_ How you are so sure?

Comment: I set let X = 0; outside of forEach and then logged X and increased it after every loop. It always remained in 0. Also when I console log childArr[1] it returns undefined

Comment: I'm not sure about that xpath, I think you want `./..` and `./*` - I would switch to css if I were you, it's less confusing.

Comment: @pguardiario That was it exactly! Thanks!!! May I ask where you found that? I followed some xpath cheat sheet but they didn't show it this way :D

Comment: Yes, you just always lead with the `./` when it's relative to an element. It's easier to get confused by xpath than css which is why I suggested switching.